# How are angular .service()'s singletons and data can be shared across controllers even though they are new'd when instantiated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see the below plain js code.

```
var newable = function() {
    this.name = 'First';
  this.setName = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  this.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

var n = new newable();
var m = new newable();

n.setName('second');
console.log(n.getName()); //second
console.log(m.getName()); //First
```

When angular services are instantiated using 'new', how can they be called singleton and can share data across controllers? Isn't 'new' misleading here?

Answer (score 1):

Services are instantiated with `new` but are singletons because new is only called once, subsequent dependency injections will simply return the existing instance. This enables controllers to access the same data on that particular service. The use of `new` only sounds misleading as it's incorrectly assumed that new is called every time the service it retrieved which it isn't personally I read it that way too but it's only called once.

I've put together a very much simplified example of how one can achieve this. I've constructed it to mimic Angular syntax so that you can better understand what might be happening behind the scenes.

```js
// var module = angular.module('myApp'); // Commented this out as I'm mocking what Angular does

var module = {
    controller: function(name, arg){
        var fn = arg.splice(arg.length - 1, 1)[0]; // Split the array and retrieve the controllers constructor
        var deps = [];
        for(var i = 0; i <  arg.length; i ++){
            deps.push(this.service(arg[i])); // retrieve or construct services
        }
        return fn.apply({}, deps); // apply dependencies with new object assigned as this
    },
    controllers: {},
    service: function (name, fn){   // Simplified version of what module.service likely does to instantiate a singleton
        if(!fn) return this.services[name]; // We're retrieving not defining a service so just return it
        if(this.services.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            return this.services[name]; // We have an instance already so just return it
        } else {
            this.services[name] =  new fn(); // No instance so create one
            return this.services[name];
        }
    },
    services: {}
};

var instances = 0;   // Global so that we can confirm the constructor is only ever called once despite new being used
function ServiceConstructor(){
    instances++;
    this.instanceId = instances;  // Allocate an instance ID based on the global
}
// Manually create a couple of services
var a = module.service('myService', ServiceConstructor);
var b = module.service('myService', ServiceConstructor);

// Create a mock controller or 2 with another service injected
var ctl = module.controller('testCtl', ['myService', function(myService){
    this.myService = myService;
   console.log(myService.instanceId);
    return this;
}]);

var ctl2 = module.controller('testCtl2', ['myService', function(myService){
    this.myService = myService;
    console.log(myService.instanceId);
    return this;
}]);

console.log(b);
console.log("Are a & b the same?", a === b);  // True
console.log("InstanceIds:", a.instanceId, b.instanceId); // 1 , 1
b.testProp = "Yep definitely the same";
console.log(a.testProp); // Yep definitely the same
console.log("Are all 4 service references the same?", (a === b) === (ctl.myService === ctl2.myService));

var c = new ServiceConstructor();  // call the services constructor manually to make sure my test logic works
console.log("Are b & c the same?", b === c) // false - c was manually instantiated
console.log ("b & c instanceid's: ", b.instanceId, c.instanceId); // 1, 2
console.log("Total instances:", instances); // 2 because we created one with module.service then one by calling the constructor directly
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services):

> Angular services are:
>
> - Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an application component depends on it.
> - Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory.

So, they get *new'd* when the first application component that depends on it gets in use, and then each other component that depends on that same service gets a reference to the **single instance** generated by the service factory.